Category of topological spaces strongly generated by a point?
In Adámek and Rosicky's book [1], they write

Thm 1.11. A category is locally finitely presentable iff it is cocomplete and has a strong generator formed by finitely presentable objects.

In the preliminaries, they define a "strong generator" in a category $\mathcal{C}$ to be a set of objects $\mathcal{G}$ such that for any object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, one can separate any subobject $i:S \hookrightarrow X$ by a morphism from $\mathcal{G}$. More precisely, there exists an object $G \in \mathcal{G}$ and a morphism $m: G \rightarrow X$ which does not factor through $i$, i.e., the following diagram does not lift
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
   @.  S \\
   @.   @VViV \\
   G @>m>> X
\end{CD}
$$
According to nlab, this, and related notions, are more commonly called "separators" nowadays.
Adámek and Rosicky further mention that finitely presentable objects in the category of topological spaces, $\mathcal{Top}$, are precisely the finite discrete topologies and that $\mathcal{Top}$ is not locally finitely presentable.
But now I was wondering if the terminal object, $*$, is a strong separator since for any topological space $X$ and each proper subspace $S < X$, we can map $*$ to any element in $X \backslash S$, for which a lift to $S$ would not exist.
So, either I am misunderstanding the theorem, or $\mathcal{Top}$ cannot be generated by a point (which is a finitely presentable object). What am I missing?

A good lesson why a topological space should not be confused with it's underlying set.

If $X$ and $S$ are topological spaces with the same underlying set, but where $S$ has a strictly finer topology, then $S$ is a “proper subobject” of $X$ in $\mathcal{\text{Top}}$ (the identity function $S\to X$ is a monomorphism in $\mathcal{\text{Top}}$ that is not an isomorphism), but there is no map $\ast\to X$ that does not factor through $S$.
